# Any Specific way to push image from jenkin to private GC artifact regisrty?

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-artifact-registry

I want to push the docker image from the Jenkins pipeline to the private GC artifact registry. how should I proceed with it?

Comment: Have you checked this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#push-tagged)?

Comment: just make sure your Jenkins Service Account has the permissions to push it to GC Artifacts Registry in the desired project.

Comment: Make sure that your Jenkins account has the correct permission to the private GC AR/CR. You can also refer to this step by step guide on [how to push docker image GCR through the Jenkins job](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-push-docker-image-to-google-container-registry-gcr-through-jenkins-job-52b9d5ce9f7f).